# perl regex - multiple pattern matching, optional matching

Tags: regex, perl

I'm stuck on this regex. Its matching 2 of my 3 file names. Need help getting all three if possible.
I also want to extract  one of these values `abc|def|ghi` as well as `ucsb|tech` locale name before the extension `.edu | .net` into variables.

Would like to do this in one pass if possible. Thanks.

```
/home/test/abc/.last_run_dir
/home/test/def/.last_file_sent.mail@wolverine.ucsb.edu
/home/test/ghi/.last_file_sent.dp3.tech.net
```

Its not picking up the first line:

```
/home/test/abc/.last_run_dir
```

Regex:

```
$line =~ m#home/test/(\w{3}).*[.](\w+)[.].*#
```

Code:

```
my $file = 'Index.lst';
open my $FILE, '<', $file or die "unable to open '$file' for reading: $!";
while (my $line = <$FILE>) {
    chomp($line);
    if ($line =~ m#home/test/(\w{3}).*[.](\w+)[.].*#) {
        open my $file2, '<', $line or die "unable to open '$file' for reading: $!";
        while(my $line2 = <$file2>) {
        print "$line2";
        }
        close $file2;
    }
} #end while
close $FILE;
```

Also, how do I print out my possible matches? If they are optional?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;

while(my $line=<DATA>) {
    chomp($line);
    if ($line =~ m#home/test/(\w{3})/\.(\w+)(?:.*\.(\w+)\.[^.]+)?|$#) {
        print "$line\n";
        print "1=$1\t2=$2\t3=$3\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
/home/test/abc/.last_run_dir
/home/test/def/.last_file_sent.mail@wolverine.ucsb.edu
/home/test/ghi/.last_file_sent.dp3.tech.net
```

#### Ouput:

```
/home/test/abc/.last_run_dir
1=abc   2=last_run_dir  3=
/home/test/def/.last_file_sent.mail@wolverine.ucsb.edu
1=def   2=last_file_sent    3=ucsb
/home/test/ghi/.last_file_sent.dp3.tech.net
1=ghi   2=last_file_sent    3=tech
```

Answer (score 3):

The part of your regex after the w{3} *forces* it to look for the next dot-word-dot:

```
[.](\w+)[.].*
```

A simple fix is to make this optional. But when you do, you'll probably need to lock down that first .*: specify that it can be any string of characters, but *not* a period.  (A good practice to do in general, btw.)

```
$line =~ m#home/test/(\w{3})[^.]*([.](\w+)[.].*)?#
```

EDIT: I see that my solution might need a bit of testing to check for the periods in the right places, fyi.

Comment: I like that you provided tips with solution :)

Comment: thanks. Also, how do I print out all my possible matches? Including the optional?

Comment: @jdamae `my ( $dir, $dom ) = $line =~ m#home/test/(\w{3})[^.]*([.](\w+)[.].*)?#`

Comment: guys, I am still stuck. i tried your suggestions. I need to extract those names i described in the question. `ucsb` or `tech` or something that will grab the name before `.edu` or `.net`

Comment: just a little utility i need for file checking. trying to learn perl. thx.

Answer (score -1):

Your regex requires two instances of "." to match.  If the second one is optional use a [.]?

```
$line =~ m#home/test/(\w{3}).*[.](\w+)[.]?.*#;
```